# Form lines based on a searched string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am new to Notepad++, I have a require met to append number of lines and make them a sing leline  based on a string, Please help me for achieving this.
Ex : Suppose I have data like

```
03/14/2010 tom m cruise fl 05/12/2009 debbie sharon wa 13/09/2008 mitchell simons fl
23/09/2007 zing huan ch
20/04/2010 john carter ls
```

The Out put I want is

```
03/14/2010 tom m cruise fl
05/12/2009 debbie sharon wa
13/09/2008 mitchell simons fl
23/09/2007 zing huan ch
20/04/2010 john carter ls
```

(Basically the search criteria should be based on date)

Comment: The question does not makes sense, your input and output is exactly the same?

Comment: Do you want a new line after each record entry?

Comment: I am Sorry, While writing the question, It came as single line,but I want to make new lines starting from a date.Hope I clarify your doubt and sorry for wrong pasting

Comment: Thanks M42 for your understanding, This the the output what I want.

Comment: The question is a bit more tricky like the date format which I have are in different pattern(i,e dd/m/yy,d/mm,yy,dd/mm/yy,dd/m/yyyy etc..),Can we get a generic reg exp to get the above output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

Find what: `(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})`
Replace with: `\n$1`

Notice the space before the group.
Be sure that `Regular expression` is checked.

If your dates are not always with 2 digits for months and days, use:

Find what: `(\d?\d/\d?\d/\d{4})`

If year is 2 or 4 digit long:

Find what: `(\d?\d/\d?\d/\d\d(?:\d\d))`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply, Still facing issue where the date format is like 1/1/99, 17/1/94, Please help to find

Comment: Hi. I wanted to do the same thing in notepad++ 6.5 but wasn't able to replace the regex with the same using ($1). It simply replaces it with new line... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi M42, Superb Solution ..but what about years?

Comment: @RazvanN : I'm working with npp 6.5.2. May be you haven't check `Regular expression`?

Comment: I did checked Regular expression.. and i put in _find what_ the expression and in _replace with_ i put this: **($1)\n**

Comment: @RazvanN: Are you using the parenthesis in the `Find what`? If yes, it should work. Else I suggest you open a new question with all relevant things: extract of the file you want to modify, exact regex you're using and what you've get after applying it.

Comment: That's the thing, 'cause it finds me the expression, but when i hit replace it doesn't replace with what i need ( the same expression and new line)

Comment: Thanks M42 for your help, really appreciate it.Kudos to you.